# NextAuth 5: Host must be trusted

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I've just successfully configured NextAuth 5 with NextJs 14 app. Then I checked out the project on another PC, created the same `.env` file and now I get the following error when navigating to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin`

```
[auth][error][N]: Host must be trusted. URL was: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin. Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#n
    at C:\Users\me\projects\my-project\.next\server\chunks\687.js:364:39815
    at nc (C:\Users\me\projects\my-project\.next\server\chunks\687.js:364:41457)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\me\projects\my-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:41304
```

with the following page

[image]

Any ideas what should be the case or which option am I missing?

.env

```
AUTH_GITHUB_ID=id
AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET=secret
AUTH_SECRET=secret generated using https://generate-secret.vercel.app/32
```

src/auth.ts

```js
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GitHub from "next-auth/providers/GitHub"
import { DrizzleAdapter } from "@auth/drizzle-adapter"
import { db } from "@/db"

export const authConfig = {
  providers: [GitHub],
  adapter: DrizzleAdapter(db),
  callbacks: {
    /* does not return ID by default */
    async session({session, user}) {
      session.user.id = user.id
      return session
    },
  }
} satisfies NextAuthConfig

export const { 
  handlers, 
  auth, 
  signOut 
} = NextAuth(authConfig)
```

src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```js
import { handlers } from "@/auth";

export const { GET, POST } = handlers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running the `npm run start` command instead of the `npm run dev`, so that `.env` was not picked up.

Answer (score 1):

You should define env vars for :
VERCEL_URL=
NEXTAUTH_URL=

or set

```
    trustHost: true
```

Comment: Setting the NEXTAUTH_URL to localhost when running `next start` locally works for me. I wouldn't recommend setting trustHost to true to accomplish this.